# Checking if unification between two elements is True or False

Tags: list, prolog

So my problem is this i have this predicate equal(X,Y) which says basically that X is equal to Y and unifies them if they are, as long as they have the same length, but what i want is the predicate to give true or false but instead, it gives me the unifications.

If somebody could help i would appreciate it a lot.

My output:

```
?- equal([[d, r, a, m, a],[a, m, e, n, o]],[[P11, P21, P31, P41, P51], [a, P23, P33, P43, P53]]).P11 = d,
P21 = r,
P31 = P51, P51 = a,
P41 = P23, P23 = m,
P33 = e,
P43 = n,
P53 = o .

?- equal([[a, m, e, n, o]],[[P11, P21, P31, P41, P51], [a, P23, P33, P43, P53]]).
false.
```

As you can see the substituitions are fine, like i want those substituitions to happen, but the i dont want them as the output, what i want is whether this is True or False which in this case is True.

Correct output:

```
?- equal([[d, r, a, m, a],[a, m, e, n, o]],[[P11, P21, P31, P41, P51], [a, P23, P33, P43, P53]]).P11 = d,
true.

?- equal([[a, m, e, n, o]],[[P11, P21, P31, P41, P51], [a, P23, P33, P43, P53]]).
false.
```

Program:

```
isSubset([],_).
isSubset([H|T],Y):-
    member(H,Y),
    select(H,Y,Z),
    isSubset(T,Z).
equal(X,Y):-
    isSubset(X,Y),
    isSubset(Y,X).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this using Lambda expressions (e.g. with the [yall](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall) library of SWI-Prolog).

Prolog will yield bindings only for those variables placed within the `{ }` before the query:

```
?- {P11, P21}/equal([[d, r, a, m, a],[a, m, e, n, o]],[[P11, P21, P31, P41, P51], [a, P23, P33, P43, P53]]).
P11 = d,
P21 = r .
```

But note that you can also leave the brackets empty and yield no bindings:

```
?- {}/equal([[d, r, a, m, a],[a, m, e, n, o]],[[P11, P21, P31, P41, P51], [a, P23, P33, P43, P53]]).
true .
```

This seems to be essentially the functionality you want. You could throw it into a helper rule to make things easier. The following will give you `true` for each valid relation for `equal/2` in the facts:

```
isEqual(X, Y) :-
    {}/equal(X, Y).
```

If you want to know only if *one or more* valid relations for `equal/2` exists in the facts, then you could add a cut `!`:

```
isEqual(X, Y) :-
    {}/equal(X, Y),
    !.
```

Output for your query is thus:

```
?- isEqual([[d, r, a, m, a],[a, m, e, n, o]],[[P11, P21, P31, P41, P51], [a, P23, P33, P43, P53]]).       
true.
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept this response if it answered your question. Cheers.